# How to Retrieve WSDL and Included XML Schemas?

Tags: xsd, wsdl

I m trying to query a wsdl by using the ?wsdl in the URL. I m able to get the complete WSDL. but the WSDL contains xsd imports with schemalocation like so
   "xsd:import namespace="httx://xxxxxxxx/fundTransfer" schemaLocation="../xxx/xxxxxx/FundTransfer.xsd"/>"

How can i query the FundTransfer.xsd from the URL.

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having?

Comment: You can retrieve the deployed wsdl byt specifying http://mycompany.com/context-path/MyWebService?wsdl. Is your wsdl is importing schema definitions from another XSD file, then he also wants to look at that XSD.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same boat as you earlier and I realized it is not possible at least with Axis 1.4. This was 1+ years back though. It might be different for different soap stacks like CXF etc. It is better to post in the forum of the soap stack vendor you are using as there is no standard defined for this.